# Capturing and testing output command in ZSH

Tags: zsh, command-substitution

I have tried countless ways to get what I want, but nothing seems to work. I always end up with something like `2:not found`.

I want to capture the output of a command, and then test if it equals "!", like so:

```
function test() {
  local testv=$(command) 2>/dev/null
  if [ $(#testv) == "!" ]; then
    echo "Exclamation mark!"
  else
    echo "No exclamation mark."
  fi
}
```

How should I rewrite the code above to avoid the error `test:2: = not found`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
if [ $testv = '!' ]; then
```

There were several problems here:

- `$(...)` runs a command and substitutes its output; you want to substitute a variable value, so use `$var` or `${var}`.
- I have no idea what the `#` was doing there.  `${#var}` will get the length of $var, but that's not what you want here.
- The `test` command (which `[` is a synonym for) doesn't understand `==`, so use `=` (if you're a C programmer that'll look *wrong*, but this is shell not C).
- I don't think this is a problem in a script, but for interactive input `"!"` doesn't do what you expect.  I used `'!'` to make sure the exclamation mark couldn't be interpreted as a history option.

Alternately, you could use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`, since it understands `==` (and has somewhat cleaner syntax in general):

```
if [[ $testv == '!' ]]; then
```

BTW, I'm trusting from the tag that this script is running in zsh; if not, the syntax will be a bit different (basic shells don't have `[[ ]]`, and anything other than zsh will do unwanted parsing on the value of $testv unless it's in double-quotes).  If you're not sure (or want it to be portable), here's a version that should work in any posix-compliant shell:

```
if [ "$testv" = '!' ]; then
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
local testv=$(command 2>/dev/null)
```

since it's the output of the command you want to redirect.

(I have no idea what you mean by `$(#testv)` though.)